# Add task to tasks list through JavaScript in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, task-list

Can't add task list item to tasks list through JavaScript in SharePoint 2013.

Here is my code:

```
$("#Button1").click(function(e){
   var siteUrl = 'http://sharepointlive:1234/';

    //function createListItem() {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('customtasks');

        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

        oListItem.set_item('Task Name', 'My New Item!');
        oListItem.set_item('Assigned To', 'administrator');
        oListItem.set_item('Task Status', 'Not Started');

        oListItem.update();

        clientContext.load(oListItem);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    //}


 });
```

Comment: Do you get some kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sharepointlive:1234/"); 

// Assume that the web has a list named "customtasks". 
List oList  = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("customtasks"); 

// We are just creating a regular list item, so we don't need to 
// set any properties. If we wanted to create a new folder, for 
// example, we would have to set properties such as 
// UnderlyingObjectType to FileSystemObjectType.Folder. 
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation(); 
ListItem newItem = oList .AddItem(itemCreateInfo); 
newItem["Task Name"] = "My New Item!"; 
newItem["Assigned To"] = "administrator"; 
newItem["Task Status"] = "Not Started"; 
newItem.Update(); 
context.ExecuteQuery();
```